# Visual Studio Open Class' File From Another File

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, if I right-click a symbol representing a class and select "Go To Definition", it shows me the file that contains the class definition but not the same way as if I were to open the file.

Instead, the tab has the title of the class' file's name, but the tab shows up on the right instead of on the left, and it is not persistent. If I right-click -> go-to-definition a different class, the new special tab overwrites the previous special tab.

If I want to actually have the file open normally so that it does not go away prematurely, how do I do that? It is a nuisance to 1) "Go To Definition" 2) Note filename 3) Go search for that file 4) Open that file (in which case the special tab moves over to the left and acts as a normally opened tab).

**How do I open a class' definition file from within another file that references it?**

I am currently using Visual Studio 15.

Comment: As so often coincidentally happens, shortly after asking this I finally found something. A workaround so short it's almost as good as having the option directly: "Go To Declaration", then right-click the special tab that shows up on the right side. In its right-click menu is a "Keep Tab Open" which seems to move it to the left and make it act like a normally opened tab. Would be nice if there was a real answer, but this workaround is so good I'll post it as an answer if nobody finds anything else.

Comment: One less click: in VS 2019 at least there is an icon the left of the tab's `x` which when clicked does the same job.

Comment: @StephenKennedy I'll probably be accepting Sergey's answer, but I suggest you turn our comments into an answer so I can upvote it for you, and more importantly for future users to benefit from (and upvote you even more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure opening new files not in a preview tab in VS **Tabs and Windows** options:

[image]